# Application of Moore-Penrose generalized inverse

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

For Hermitian positive semidefnite matrices $A$ and $B$. Let $C=A+B$, if $C$ is invertible, then we can easily get $$I=X+Y,$$ where $X=C^{-\frac{1}{2}}AC^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and $Y=C^{-\frac{1}{2}}BC^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

But if $C$ is not invertible, I can  use the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse $C^+$ to get the required result $$I=X+Y$$ with $X=(C^+)^{\frac{1}{2}}A(C^+)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $Y=(C^+)^{\frac{1}{2}}B(C^+)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

In this example. it is trivial that $range(A)\subseteq range(C)$ and $range(B)\subseteq range(C)$. But if both $A$ and $B$ are not Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices, $range(A)\varsubsetneq range(C)$, $range(B)\varsubsetneq range(C)$, and $C=A+B$ is not invertible, can I use the  Moore-Penrose generalized inverse to get $I=X+Y$?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't get $I=X+Y$ at all if $C$ is not invertible. You want to get $I=(C^+)^{1/2}(A+B)(C^+)^{1/2}$, so range $C=A+B$ must not be less than range $I$.

Comment: Actually, I want  to know why range matters here.

Comment: In other words, if $A+B$ is degenerate, $I$ must be degenerate.